# Phonegap - Printing bluetooth

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, zebra-printers

I have the following problem:

I have a MZ320 printer Zebra works by bluetooth, but application is under develop phonegap.

I found this plugin (https://github.com/EionRobb/phonegap-print-plugins), but do not know how to implement it (and install).

I am a neophyte at this, please help.

My English sucks, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I pushed on Github a simple cordova/phonegap plugin to send ZPL data to printer. Use it is very simple. Visit [project page](https://github.com/mmilidoni/zbtprinter) for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the plugin you referenced. I can suggest two ways: (1) Embed [Zebra SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/zebralink.html) in your app and use it to implement printer discovery, connection and printing to MZ320. (2) Use [centvia](http://www.centsoftware.com/centvia) app to handle printer discovery, connection, and communications and invoke it from your app to send your print data to the MZ320.